# Bootstrap Datepicker not close when tab over

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker for selecting date (one of three fields) for my application. On problem I have is: if I tab through the field, the datepicker dropdown will not close. Can anyone help?

I believe we are using jquery-1.8.3

Comment: You believe you are using jquery 1.8.3? Why aren't you certain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this was a bug with *autoclose: true* and *todayBtn: true*. Not so bad with *todayBtn: 'linked'*, as the actual date would be changed before the picker was hidden. Fixed [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/commit/bf1b2c820076e3e11b0199abe43d00ddcc645995).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I found that the js file you posted is not the same as mine. Is there a way to work around by writing my own js function to fix that such as event handling? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried downloading the new version of the jar file? This would fix your problem I think... the code is here https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: :))) I'm happy for this! bye